# Rocket Universe Data load

Tags: universe, u2, rocket

I'm trying to do a dataload into a Rocket Universe database.  In going through the SQL Admin documentation, they give the following example, but very little in the way of describing what is going on with the config file.  Can anyone shed a little more light on how the config file is defined?  Any example resources on this?  Thanks!

The following is an example of a data file:

```
tomr:"Tom" '"'Thomas Rand^29:77:240:"blond"green:Kevin
lisam:Lisa Michaels^28:66:130:"brown"brown:Troy
kellyv:Kelly Verock^37:72:180:"black"brown:none
paulv:Paul Vander^33:63:110:"brown"brown:Trisha
andyu:Andy Andrews^28:74:250:"blond"blue:none
ken:Ken Thompson^35:73:170:"grayy"blue:Peter
tim:Tim Tarks^35:75:180:"black"brown:none
steve:Steve Gough^35:68:180:"black"green:Nancy
ellen:Ellen Peters^33:75:220:"black"brown:Michael
derek:Derek Starks^34:66:120:"brown"brown:Karissa

The following example shows the corresponding configuration file:

FILE NUMBER: 1
    LOCATION: ../dataloader/names2.data
    Row Separator CHARACTER(S): 10
    COLUMN SEPARATOR CHARACTER(S): :
    QUOTE CHARACTER: "
    ALTERNATE QUOTE CHARACTER: '
        COLUMN NUMBER: 1
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        COLUMN NUMBER: 2
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        NEXT SEPARATOR CHARACTER(S): ^
        COLUMN NUMBER: 3
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        COLUMN NUMBER: 4
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        COLUMN NUMBER: 5
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        COLUMN NUMBER: 6
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        WIDTH: 7
        COLUMN NUMBER: 7
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW
        COLUMN NUMBER: 8
        SOURCE FORMAT: RAW

DESTINATION FILE:
    LOCATION: TMP5950
    AUTOSIZE: n
    AUTOSIZE ROWS:
    CREATE FILE: N
    PARAMETER(S):
    KEY COLUMN(S): KEY1
        COLUMN NUMBER: KEY
        COLUMN NAME: KEY1
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 1
        COLUMN NUMBER: 1
        COLUMN NAME: COL1
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 1
        COLUMN NUMBER: KEY
        COLUMN NAME: KEY2
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 2
        COLUMN NUMBER: 2
        COLUMN NAME: COL2
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 2
        COLUMN NUMBER: KEY
        COLUMN NAME: KEY3
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 3
        COLUMN NUMBER: 3
        COLUMN NAME: COL3
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 3
        COLUMN NUMBER: 4
        COLUMN NAME: COL4
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 4
        CONVERSION TYPE: O
        CONVERSION CODE: MD2
        COLUMN NUMBER: 5
        COLUMN NAME: COL5
        SOURCE FILE NUMBER(S): 1
        SOURCE COLUMN NUMBER(S): 8

>DATALOAD 5950.CONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20%2Funiverse%2Fv11.2.4%2Funiverse_sqldbaadminguide_v1124.pdf) define the config file enough for you - on page 5-42 there is a table.

Comment: Yes, certainly I saw that table.  That would be just above the place where I cut and pasted the example that I posted to this site.  For me, that description or definition table leaves a lot to be desired.  This table assumes a lot of additional knowledge on the part of the reader.  So I was hoping to get some additional details/examples from the community. -- Thanks.

Comment: the file is in two parts, one to define the source - i.e. columns with their delimiters and quotes, catering for csv/tsv etc and then the definition of the target file, which would be a universe table, so again the columns need defining together with their types etc.  Is there a particular part of the config file you need help with ?